# C Program Time Conversion

Tags: c, time

I came upon this Time Conversion Program in HackerRank, I was surprised the way how the program is compiled in HackerRank (or could be my misunderstanding of C).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int hh, mm, ss;
    char tt[2];
    scanf("%d:%d:%d%s", &hh, &mm, &ss, tt);
    printf("%d\n", hh);
    if(strcmp(tt, "PM") == 0 && hh != 12) hh += 12;
    if(strcmp(tt, "AM") == 0 && hh == 12) hh = 0;
    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", hh, mm, ss);
    return 0;
}
```

The above program, when I ran in my computer, using MinGW 32-bit GCC Compiler, I was getting the value of hh as zero.

[image]

Fine, I thought could be compiler issue and ran the code in IDEONE, same results.

[image]

But when I ran this same code with HackerRank, all testcases were passed, I have no idea, how this is working here?

[image]

I am confused at this stage, am I doing this right?

Comment: You are 1-char short on `char tt[2];` You forgot about the *nul-terminating* character. You need at minimum `char tt[3] = "";` to hold `AM` or `PM` (the initialization is just good practice)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, how does variable hh return zero, just because of char pointer is having a shorter storage space? and how does it run on hackerrank?

Comment: It runs poorly. You invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @cs1193 It depends on the layout of variables on the stack. If `tt` is right before `hh`, the final nul character will overwrite the first byte of `hh`, setting it to zero on a little endian architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the changes made to allow space in `tt` to accommodate the *nul-terminating* character, the code functions well in making conversions to military time. By initializing `tt` to zero all elements during declaration/definition, you have insure `tt` will be nul-terminated when AM or PM are added. e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    int hh, mm, ss;
    char tt[3] = "";

    printf (" enter time in HH:MM:SS AM/PM: ");
    if (scanf ("%d:%d:%d %[^\n]%*c", &hh, &mm, &ss, tt) != 4) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid read of time.\n");
    }

    hh = (strcmp (tt, "PM") == 0 && hh != 12) ? hh + 12 : hh;
    if (strcmp (tt, "AM") == 0 && hh == 12) hh = 0;
    printf (" %02d:%02d:%02d\n\n", hh, mm, ss);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/tmread
 enter time in HH:MM:SS AM/PM: 11:59:04 PM
 23:59:04
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: scanf with "%s" is dangerous, since it does not limit the string length. See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d.aspx or other places for how to avoid this problem in general.

Comment: Agreed, it can always be replaced with `"%[^\n]%*c"` which is probably the better solution. It was originally left as `%s` since we were dealing with `AM`, `PM` in a fixed format file, it avoided having to discuss the use of the *assignment suppression* operator, etc...